# Is it possible to get merchant prices using Amazon Marketplace Web service?

Tags: amazon-mws

I am currently exploring Amazon Marketplace Web Service to see if I can get a list of Merchant prices (Item Price and Shipping Price) if I give an ASIN as input. Here are operations I came across which may be helpful

- GetCompetitivePricingForSKU
- GetCompetitivePricingForASIN

and

- GetLowestOfferListingsForSKU
- GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN

The GetLowestOfferListing based on SKU and ASIN returns the lowest price offer listings for a specific product. I was thinking that GetCompetitivePricing for SKU and ASIN would return pricing information for all merchants but it returns only the lowest priced merchant information.

Is there a way using Amazon MWS to get a list of all merchants with their sale and shipping price if I give ASIN or SKU as input?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon used to have this feature using the PA-API for sellers when sellers were using a whitelisted account, as of 31st Aug 2012 Amazon removed the OfferFull response group and forced sellers to move to the MWS api.

MWS does not have this feature and from what I can find out, It has been removed and will never return.